# Multi processing with .so python libraries in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, cpython, process-pool

I am trying to execute a code similar to the following:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from example_module import function

argument_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
parex = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
res = parex.map(function, argument_list)
print(list(res))
```

which works fine in general. However, this code breaks when I use a specific module in *module_example*. Looking at the source code of this specific module, I realized that it imports some objects using

```
from .lib import func
```

from a file with the name lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.
Does anybody know whether this is for some reason incompatible with *ProcessPoolExecutor*??
Thanks a lot to everyone!

EDIT: The code works well when executed from a script. It is when executing it in a jupyter notebook that it fails.

Comment: it's recommended to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard when running multiprocessing.

Comment: can you post the full error?

Comment: Actually no error message is printed, the line `res = parex.map(function, argument_list)` is executed instantaneously, but the line `print(list(res))` never finishes.